# How to configure sonar.junit.reportPaths

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, java-11, gradle-plugin, jacoco-plugin

I have tried severally to configure this sonarqube property `sonar.junit.reportPaths` within Gradle but still get the same error message.

Gradle version -> 6.7.1

SonarQube Server version -> 8.9 (docker image)

Java version -> openjdk 11.0.2

Intellij version -> 2021.1.2

My Sonarqube Gradle configuration is as below:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'jacoco'
    id "org.sonarqube" version "3.3"
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.5.20'
}
```

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property 'sonar.projectName', 'Snippets of Java code'
        property 'sonar.junit.reportPaths', 'build/test-results/test'
        property 'sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths', 'build/reports/test/jacocoTestReport.xml'
        property 'sonar.inclusions', '*.java,*.kt'
    }
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.required = true
        csv.required = false
    }
}
```

I still get the message below:

```
Resource not found: com.sammy.service.JavaFareTest under the directory /Users/samuelifere/IdeaProjects/codingChallenges while reading test reports. Please, make sure your "sonar.junit.reportPaths" property is configured properly
Resource not found: com.sammy.model.JavaCardTest under the directory /Users/samuelifere/IdeaProjects/codingChallenges while reading test reports. Please, make sure your "sonar.junit.reportPaths" property is configured properly
```

I read several stackoverflow pages such as these:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47265816/sonarqube-ignores-sonar-junit-reportpaths), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59567039/0-coverage-in-the-sonarqube-report-for-the-kotlin-project/59575711#59575711) but still didn't help in resolving my issue. Any help would be much appreciated, so it can properly find the resources.

The command I use to run to run this through Gradle is:

```
./gradlew clean build jacocoTestReport sonarqube
```

Comment: Why are you trying to configure the property? The default value doesn't work correctly? The same question apply to `sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths`?

Comment: The default for this property `sonar.junit.reportPaths` doesn't work. The other one for the jacoco xml path isn't needed. Issue still remains regardless of whether that property is configured or not, so it seems to be ignored somehow.

Comment: Same issue here. Did you find a solution? I tried a few things with no result

Comment: Same issue. Any resolution?

Comment: I've still being unable to find a suitable solution as it is actually. Sorry guys, still searching.

Comment: Any update @Sammy65. I am still Facing the same issue

Comment: Same issue for gradle, worked for kotlin

Comment: I still haven't found a solution for this people. 
@ValentynKolesnikov, are you saying it'll work in a build.gradle.kts?

Comment: The issue was resolved a few days ago without any modifications to the application's code

Comment: @ValentynKolesnikov Oh great! How was it sorted then? Was it a Gradle issue which got resolved in a new version?

Comment: I believe this is connected to the responses generated by the server.

Comment: The problem has resurfaced

Comment: Just upgraded our project to Gradle 8.3 and Java 17. Now I'm also finding this error when trying to run sonar.

Comment: Any update on this error.